# Angular File Upload, jCrop, and Rotate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, angularjs-directive, jcrop

I am using this angular file uploader directive (with modifications):http://nervgh.github.io/pages/angular-file-upload/examples/image-preview/.

I was able to get the source and redraw the image so it is larger. One of my requirements is that user should be able to crop and rotate that image.

I planned on using jCrop, but I am unable to get it to work and am at a loss. The jcrop-holder appears in the HTML, but it has width and height of 0.

My code is here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/bC3g58ZdTGGJeoueipnQ?p=preview

Would anyone have any suggestions on what I could do to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My colleague solved my problem and I hope this will help others!

https://github.com/LukeMason/angular-img-editor

Comment: You and your colleague did an amazing job with the demo I saw.  I have high hopes of using what you made however I'm unable to actually view the file I upload.  I see that you can view and edit saved files but how do you view and edit files before you saved them?

Comment: glad you found this useful! so I can understand what you are trying to solve, can you put your bug into a plunkr?

Comment: I would've but I was working on this days ago and found a different, simpler solution good enough for my MVP and I don't really know how to use plunk.  Sorry I can't be more helpful. I really pulled my hair out over this and the thought of going back to it right now turns my stomach . . .

Comment: @rashadb can you please tell which solution you implemented for this purpose.

Comment: @user3495469 I have downloaded your code from github, I am not able to view the file that I upload and also does it support multiple file upload. Can you give a working demo if possible.

Comment: @pratik I would suggest that you put in an issue in the github repo. It does support multiple file upload. There is a plunkr in the README.md in the github repo. I believe the author of angular file uploader updated his library that's why the plunkr is out of date.